# How can I change the name of the Schema dynamically in JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am using JPA to query flyway_schema_history to print a report of the executed migrations. The structure of flyway_schema_history is repeated across all the schemas in my Postgresql database. Also, I am passing the name of the schema as a parameter when I run the program.I am using Java 10.

I created this entity in JPA.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "flyway_schema_history", schema="this_should_be dynamic")
public class FlywaySchemaHistoryGeneric {

    @Id
    @Column(name="installed_rank")
    private Integer installedRank;

    @Column(name="version")
    private String version;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name="script")
    private String script;

    @Column(name="checksum")
    private Integer checksum;

    @Column(name="installed_by")
    private String installedBy;

    @Column(name="installed_on")
    private Date installedOn;

    @Column(name="execution_time")
    private Integer executionTime;

    @Column(name="success")
    private Boolean success;


    public Integer getInstalledRank() {
        return installedRank;
    }

    public void setInstalledRank(Integer installedRank) {
        this.installedRank = installedRank;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getScript() {
        return script;
    }

    public void setScript(String script) {
        this.script = script;
    }

    public Integer getChecksum() {
        return checksum;
    }

    public void setChecksum(Integer checksum) {
        this.checksum = checksum;
    }

    public String getInstalledBy() {
        return installedBy;
    }

    public void setInstalledBy(String installedBy) {
        this.installedBy = installedBy;
    }

    public Date getInstalledOn() {
        return installedOn;
    }

    public void setInstalledOn(Date installedOn) {
        this.installedOn = installedOn;
    }

    public Integer getExecutionTime() {
        return executionTime;
    }

    public void setExecutionTime(Integer executionTime) {
        this.executionTime = executionTime;
    }

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }
}
```

I was trying to use FlywaySchemaHistoryGeneric.class.getAnnotation to change the value in runtime without success, but I think that it should be an easy way to do it.
How can I do to make schema from @table to be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wont be able to modidy that in runtime because annotations are read-only. You can create one datasource for each schema and choose one of them to persist the entity based in your rules.